# Vraptor teste unitário Mockito (CDI)

Tags: java, vraptor

alguém pode me dar uma luz, de como fazer os testes unitários utilizando o Mockito junto ao completo CDI da aplicação do Vraptor?

Uso bastante o CDI para controlar meus objetos como gerenciamento automátio da minha dao junto ao manager com o @Inject.

Mais ao utilizar os testes unitários o mesmo não está instanciando esses meus objetos que deveriam ser injetados automaticamente.

Se eu der um @InjectMocks na minha Dao, beleza, mais o @inject dentro da classe Dao que recebe meu EntityManager não funciona, e não é injetado.

Tentei então fazer o @InjectMocks no EntityManager e instanciar minha classe Dao na mão passando ela, mais sem sucesso. Pelo visto o inject do Mock não tem poder para fazer isto no EntityManager.

Alguem pode me dar uma luz?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É que não funciona assim como você pensa, quando você está executando os testes unitários você esta em um contexto standalone, tudo deve ser feito de forma braçal mesmo, ex: se você deseja testar seus repositórios(DAO's) você poderia criar uma suite de testes onde você tem uma classe abstrata que todos seus testes devem extender, ela será responsável por cria a fábrica, criar a entityManager, iniciar uma transação, comitar e depois destruir os recursos, isso vai rodar para cada um dos testes, testando tudo de maneira isolada, só que veja o detalhe, você quer testar repositórios(DAO's) e isso deixou de ser um teste unitário para ser teste de integração, ex:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;

/**
 * Classe abstrata utilizada para testes, responsável por abrir conexão com
 * HSQLDB e encerrar os recursos após uso.
 *
 * @author Dilnei Cunha
 */
public abstract class AbstractRepositoryTest {

    protected static EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
    protected static EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Abrindo conexão com o Database, criando a EntityManager e abrindo a
     * transação.
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp0() {
        emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("seu-ejbPU-test");
        em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    /**
     * Comita a transação, encerra a EntityManager e a factory.
     */
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown0() {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Se você está acostumado com o desenvolvimento de testes, você sabe que deve utilizar um persistence.xml para os testes que fica em

> src\test\resources\META-INF\persistemce.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="seu-ejbPU-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>br.com.suaApp.model.entity.SuaEntidade</class>
        .... suas classes 
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:meubanco-test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

No meu caso para testes de repositórios eu geralmente utilizo bancos em memória, então para cada teste eu insiro os registros referente ao repositório que será testado, perceba também que na action eu utilizo drop-and-create onde cada vez que eu rodo os testes eu destruo tudo e crio novamente, não sei se utiliza containers enterprise(servidores de aplicação JavaEE full) mas perceba que o transactinal type é RESOURCE_LOCAL e não JTA se for o caso.

exemplo de como ficaria o teste de um repositório:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SeuObjetoRepositoryTest extends AbstractRepositoryTest {

    private SeuObjetoRepository repository;
    private SeuObjeto seuObjeto1;
    private SeuObjeto seuObjeto2;

        repository = new SeuObjectoRepository(em);

        seuObjeto1 = new SeuObjeto(1L, "Joao", "teste", "12345678987");
        seuObjeto1 = repository.salvar(seuObjeto1);
        em.refresh(seuObjeto1);

        seuObjeto2 = new SeuObjeto(2L, "Zeneida", "teste2", "12345678987");
        seuObjeto2 = repository.salvar(seuObjeto2);
        em.refresh(seuObjeto2);
       ....
    }

    @Test
    public void testBuscaListaSeusObjetos() {
        List<SeuObjeto> objetos = repository.buscarLista();
        assertThat(objetos, contains(seuObjeto2, seuObjeto1));
        assertThat(objetos, not(contains(seuObjeto2, seuObjeto1)));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        repository.excluir(seuObjeto1);
        repository.excluir(seuObjeto2);
        ....destruir tudo no final da execução do teste.
    }
}
```

Para testar os serviços, você deve usar Mocks como você já deve saber, pois como seus repositórios já foram testados eles não devem ser testados novamente, se seu serviço utiliza o repositório ele deve ser mockado, ex:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

/**
 * @author Dilnei Cunha
 */
public class SeuObjetoServiceBeanTest {

    private seuObjetoServiceLocal seuObjetoServiceBean;

    @Mock
    private SeuObjetoRepository seuObjetoRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        seuObjetoServiceBean = new SeuObjetoServiceBean(seuObjetoRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuaLogicaDeNegociosDependedoOQueOServicoFaz() {

        when(seuObjetoDatabase).thenReturn(seuObjeto);
        ........
    }
        ......... demais testes
}
```

A outras opções para testes, se você deseja que seus testes pareçam como se fosse a aplicação real funcionando com tudo integrado, então você deveria utilziar uma engine de testes como o [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/), eu uso é é muito poderoso, inclusive no momento dos testes eu subo um container embedded como Wildfly e consigo testar todas injeções e dependências, porém a forma de programar isso muda, no inicio talvez seja um pouco arduo configurar ele, mas já seria assunto para um outro post, espero que eu tenha te ajudado em algo, abração.

Comment: Era o que eu tinha em mente realmente, ter que construir tudo na mão como o EntityFactory e etc...

Tinha ficado com dúvida pois no post de testas do site do Vraptor, dizia que existiam recursos para fazer desta forma, então não achei muito assim que diretamente quais recursos seriam. Mais seu post ajudou bastante pra mim entender como funciona.